# Javascript: check image exist in file system when passed by image path(String)

Tags: javascript, components

I want to create a component which consist with one local image and a title associated, both of the image and title will be passed in as String type, the component like this:

```
export default ({ image = "./default.png", title }) => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require(image)}/>
        <Text>{title}</Text>
    </View>
);
```

the invoker would looks like:

```
...
    <ImageWithTitle image={"./XXX.png"} title={"Title"} />
...
```

I have one question here:

Before render the image, how can I check if the image exists?

New to Javascript world, any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Research how to create an image preloader. The only assign image to state when image exists

Comment: I think it should be `({ image = "./default.png", title }) => (....)` instead of `({ image = "./default.png", title }) = (...)`. Use `=>` not `=`.

Comment: you could look into the `fetch` api, and check for a 200 response? You could then turn the response into a data-url with the blob api and assign it as the src value.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

there's actually an example of exactly that under "checking that the fetch was successful" on this page:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @Titus typo, updated.

Comment: @dgeare to my situation, I only want to get the image file locally(in the local file system). Seems like Fetch is on another use case.